# why " :l " disappeared in zsh script

Tags: zsh

I wrote a function in my .zshrc:

```
cnj(){
    port=0;
    echo -n "Enter number of port > ";
    read port;

    a="ssh -N -f -L localhost:$port:localhost:$port  name@ip";
    echo $a;
}
```

the result shows that :

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8909ocalhost:8909 name@ip
```

why

```
:l
```

disappear in

```
localhost:8909ocalhost:8909
```

Comment: Can edit your question and elaborate about what you doing and what error you getting ?

Comment: @ThiruShetty: The question seems pretty clear to me. The echoed string does not contain all the characters the OP expects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an instance of the [colon modifier syntax](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers).

`$var:l` in particular converts the contents of `$var` to lowercase.

To prevent `:l` being interpreted as modifier you can add braces around the variable name:

```
"...${port}:localhost:..."
```

Comment: You already edited your answer but still: using `$foo\:l` inside a double quoted string seems to output the backlash itself as well.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, that's why I removed it. :-)

Comment: Just wanted to point this out before others are wondering why you are not suggesting to use ``\`` :)

Comment: You are absolutely a genius!!